# How to use Service Account key in python script

Tags: firebase

I'm confused, how I'm supposed to use Service Account key in python script.

I have firebase realtime database, and using my Service Account key I can access database from script (and script can do what it does)

But, I saw (and GitHub complains), that if I upload my Service Account key, it says security risk.

So I need to use one database (all users where python script is distributed, need to access same database), but how they are going to access it if I don't authenticate somehow (with Service Account key).

All tutorials, explain to using Service Account key, but how I can use it when python script is intended for multiple people (to use same database (mine)) ?